# I tried to do BLE with ESP32, but the notifyCallback doesn't work

Tags: arduino, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, esp32

This text has been translated, so it may be poorly written.

Hello, I am trying to use M5stack to get the acceleration and ECG of my Polar OH1+, but the notifyCallback is not working.

I found some code in Python that did something similar, so I followed the same procedure to make the connection.

https://github.com/pareeknikhil/biofeedback/blob/master/Polar%20Device%20Data%20Stream/Accelerometer/main.py

According to this, I found out that this is the procedure to follow.

- Read the value of pmd control uuid
- Write to the pmd control uuid
- Read the pmd data uuid

The following program tries to achieve that with M5stack.

```
//===== header file & define & global variable ===== 
#include"BLEDevice.h"

boolean doConnect = false;
volatile boolean isConnected = false;
boolean doScan = false;

BLEUUID pmd_serviceUUID ("FB005C80-02E7-F387-1CAD-8ACD2D8DF0C8");
BLEUUID pmd_dataUUID ("FB005C82-02E7-F387-1CAD-8ACD2D8DF0C8");
BLEUUID pmd_ctrlUUID ("FB005C81-02E7-F387-1CAD-8ACD2D8DF0C8");
BLEAdvertisedDevice* myDevice;
BLEClient* pClient;

String SensorName = "Polar OH1 87C4C425"; // SDから読み取る
//===========================================


//===== class & function ====================
class MyClientCallback: public BLEClientCallbacks{
  void onConnect(BLEClient* pclient){ }
  void onDisconnect(BLEClient* pclient){
    isConnected = false;
    Serial.println("onDisconnetct");  
  }
};

// BLEデバイスを検索する
class MyAdvertisedDeviceCallback: public BLEAdvertisedDeviceCallbacks{
  void onResult(BLEAdvertisedDevice advertisedDevice) {
    Serial.println(advertisedDevice.toString().c_str());
    // 指定デバイスなら接続する
    if(SensorName.equals(advertisedDevice.getName().c_str())){
      Serial.print("Connect BLE device : ");
      Serial.println(advertisedDevice.toString().c_str());
      BLEDevice::getScan()->stop();
      myDevice = new BLEAdvertisedDevice(advertisedDevice);
      doConnect = true;
      doScan = true;
    }
  }
};

void notifyCallback(BLERemoteCharacteristic* pBLERemoteCharacteristic, uint8_t* pData, size_t length, bool isNotify){
  Serial.print("Notify callback for characteristic ");
  Serial.print(pBLERemoteCharacteristic->getUUID().toString().c_str());
  Serial.print(" of data length ");
  Serial.println(length);
  Serial.print("data: ");
  for (int i = 0; i <= length - 1; i++) {
    Serial.print(String(*(pData + i), HEX));
    Serial.print(" ");
  }
  Serial.println();
}

bool connectToServer(){
  Serial.print("connection to : ");
  Serial.println(myDevice->getAddress().toString().c_str());
  pClient = BLEDevice::createClient();
  Serial.println(" - Created client");
  pClient->setClientCallbacks(new MyClientCallback() );
  pClient->connect(myDevice);
  Serial.println(" - Created to server");

  BLERemoteService* pRemoteService = pClient->getService(pmd_serviceUUID);
  if (pRemoteService == nullptr) {
     Serial.println("Failed to find our service UUID: ");
     Serial.println(pmd_serviceUUID.toString().c_str());
     pClient->disconnect();
     return false;
  }
  Serial.print(" - Found service ( ");
  Serial.print(pmd_serviceUUID.toString().c_str());
  Serial.println(" )");

  static BLERemoteCharacteristic* pControlCharacteristic;
  pControlCharacteristic = pRemoteService->getCharacteristic(pmd_ctrlUUID);
  if( pControlCharacteristic == nullptr ){
    Serial.print("Failed to find out characteristic UUID : ");
    Serial.println(pmd_ctrlUUID.toString().c_str());
    pClient->disconnect();
    return false;
  }

  Serial.println("characteristics");
  std::map<uint16_t, BLERemoteCharacteristic*>* mapCharacteristics = pRemoteService->getCharacteristicsByHandle();
  for (std::map<uint16_t, BLERemoteCharacteristic*>::iterator i = mapCharacteristics->begin(); i != mapCharacteristics->end(); ++i) {
    Serial.print(" - characteristic UUID : ");
    Serial.print(i->second->getUUID().toString().c_str());
    Serial.print(" Broadcast:");
    Serial.print(i->second->canBroadcast()?'O':'X');
    Serial.print(" Read:");
    Serial.print(i->second->canRead()?'O':'X');
    Serial.print(" WriteNoResponse:");
    Serial.print(i->second->canWriteNoResponse()?'O':'X');
    Serial.print(" Write:");
    Serial.print(i->second->canWrite()?'O':'X');
    Serial.print(" Notify:");
    Serial.print(i->second->canNotify()?'O':'X');
    Serial.print(" Indicate:");
    Serial.print(i->second->canIndicate()?'O':'X');
    Serial.println();
  }

  static BLERemoteCharacteristic* pDataCharacteristic;
  pDataCharacteristic = pRemoteService->getCharacteristic(pmd_dataUUID);
    if( pDataCharacteristic == nullptr ){
    Serial.print("Failed to find out characteristic UUID : ");
    Serial.println(pmd_dataUUID.toString().c_str());
    pClient->disconnect();
    return false;
  }
  Serial.print(" - Add Notify ( ");
  Serial.print(pmd_dataUUID.toString().c_str());
  Serial.println(" )");
  
  if(pDataCharacteristic->canNotify()){
    std::string value = pControlCharacteristic->readValue();
    
    uint8_t data[14] = {0x02,
                        0x02,
                        0x00,
                        0x01,
                        0xC8,
                        0x00,
                        0x01,
                        0x01,
                        0x10,
                        0x00,
                        0x02,
                        0x01,
                        0x08,
                        0x00,};
    pControlCharacteristic->writeValue(data,14,false);
    Serial.println(" - Set value");
    
    Serial.println(" - Can Notify");
    pDataCharacteristic->registerForNotify(notifyCallback);
  }
  
  isConnected = true;
  return true;
}
//===========================================


//===== setting =============================
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Starting Arduino BLE Client application...");
  BLEDevice::init("");
  static BLEScan* pBLEScan = BLEDevice::getScan();
  pBLEScan->setAdvertisedDeviceCallbacks(new MyAdvertisedDeviceCallback());
  pBLEScan->setInterval(1349);
  pBLEScan->setWindow(449);
  pBLEScan->setActiveScan(true);
  pBLEScan->start(5, false);
}
//===========================================


//===== main ================================
void loop(){
  if(doConnect==true){
    if(connectToServer()){
      Serial.println("now connected to BLE Server.");
    }else{
      Serial.println("faild to connect to the server.");
    }
    doConnect = false;
  }

  if( isConnected == false && doScan == true ) BLEDevice::getScan()->start(0);
  delay(1000);
}
//===========================================
```

When this was done, the serial monitor display looked like the following.

```
Starting Arduino BLE Client application...
Name: , Address: 5a:f3:e5:97:72:be, manufacturer data: 060001092006319b0f7cab7c18b3ad1f11d4f6475cf638678bd51cf02d
Name: , Address: 33:20:7d:41:97:52, serviceUUID: 0000fd6f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Name: , Address: 11:27:f2:c5:92:98, manufacturer data: 0600010920029ac7ae5b723ad210a6450c28780429ca56a82bae79a076
Name: Polar OH1 87C4C425, Address: a0:9e:1a:87:c4:c4, manufacturer data: 6b00720851a77b02000000007a01053b005d, serviceUUID: 0000180d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, serviceUUID: 0000feee-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
Connect BLE device : Name: Polar OH1 87C4C425, Address: a0:9e:1a:87:c4:c4, manufacturer data: 6b00720851a77b02000000007a01053b005d, serviceUUID: 0000180d-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb, serviceUUID: 0000feee-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
connection to : a0:9e:1a:87:c4:c4
 - Created client
 - Created to server
 - Found service ( fb005c80-02e7-f387-1cad-8acd2d8df0c8 )
characteristics
 - characteristic UUID : fb005c81-02e7-f387-1cad-8acd2d8df0c8 Broadcast:X Read:O WriteNoResponse:X Write:O Notify:X Indicate:O
 - characteristic UUID : fb005c82-02e7-f387-1cad-8acd2d8df0c8 Broadcast:X Read:X WriteNoResponse:X Write:X Notify:O Indicate:X
 - Add Notify ( fb005c82-02e7-f387-1cad-8acd2d8df0c8 )
 - Set value
 - Can Notify
now connected to BLE Server.
```

It even shows Can Notify, but notyfiCallback does not work. Can you please tell me why it is not working?

Also, the byte sequence that is written to pmd control is supposed to be based on this page.

https://github.com/polarofficial/polar-ble-sdk/blob/master/technical_documentation/Polar_Measurement_Data_Specification.pdf

Also, this is the output of the serial monitor when the CoreDebugLebel of the ESP32 is set to Debug in the ArduinoIDE.

```
Starting Arduino BLE Client application...
[D][BLEAdvertisedDevice.cpp:472] setRSSI(): - setRSSI(): rssi: -83
[D][BLEAdvertisedDevice.cpp:292] parseAdvertisement(): Type: 0xff (), length: 29, data: 0600010920021a14c867a55d256f3c35b8286b3c90bfe1fa95ce255ccb
[D][BLEAdvertisedDevice.cpp:449] setManufacturerData(): - manufacturer data: 0600010920021a14c867a55d256f3c35b8286b3c90bfe1fa95ce255ccb
Name: , Address: 7e:0a:d2:c6:94:26, manufacturer data: 0600010920021a14c867a55d256f3c35b8286b3c90bfe1fa95ce255ccb
[D][BLEAdvertisedDevice.cpp:472] setRSSI(): - setRSSI(): rssi: -84
[D][BLEAdvertisedDevice.cpp:292] parseAdvertisement(): Type: 0xff (), length: 29, data: 06000109200670be05b68e63a90d3ca0a091e9c4982a95f8f08888583f
[D][BLEAdvertisedDevice.cpp:449] setManufacturerData(): - manufacturer data: 06000109200670be05b68e63a90d3ca0a091e9c4982a95f8f08888583f
Name: , Address: 71:56:ce:5b:12:af, manufacturer data: 06000109200670be05b68e63a90d3ca0a091e9c4982a95f8f08888583f
[D][BLEAdvertisedDevice.cpp:472] setRSSI(): - setRSSI(): rssi: -40
[D][BLEAdvertisedDevice.cpp:292] parseAdvertisement(): Type: 0x01 (), length: 1, data: 04
[D][BLEAdvertisedDevice.cpp:292] parseAdvertisement(): Type: 0xff (), length: 15, data: 6b00720851a77b02000000003f0043
[D][BLEAdvertisedDevice.cpp:449] setManufacturerData(): - manufacturer data: 6b00720851a77b02000000003f0043
[D][BLEAdvertisedDevice.cpp:292] parseAdvertisement(): Type: 0x09 (), length: 18, data: 506f6c6172204f4831203837433443343235
[D][BLEAdvertisedDevice.cpp:461] setName(): - setName(): name: Polar OH1 87C4C425
Name: Polar OH1 87C4C425, Address: a0:9e:1a:87:c4:c4, manufacturer data: 6b00720851a77b02000000003f0043
Connect BLE device : Name: Polar OH1 87C4C425, Address: a0:9e:1a:87:c4:c4, manufacturer data: 6b00720851a77b02000000003f0043
connection to : a0:9e:1a:87:c4:c4
 - Created client
[I][BLEDevice.cpp:614] addPeerDevice(): add conn_id: 0, GATT role: client
[D][BLEDevice.cpp:148] gattClientEventHandler(): gattClientEventHandler [esp_gatt_if: 4] ... Unknown
[D][BLEClient.cpp:177] gattClientEventHandler(): gattClientEventHandler [esp_gatt_if: 4] ... Unknown
[D][BLEDevice.cpp:148] gattClientEventHandler(): gattClientEventHandler [esp_gatt_if: 4] ... Unknown
[D][BLEClient.cpp:177] gattClientEventHandler(): gattClientEventHandler [esp_gatt_if: 4] ... Unknown
[D][BLEDevice.cpp:148] gattClientEventHandler(): gattClientEventHandler [esp_gatt_if: 4] ... Unknown
[D][BLEClient.cpp:177] gattClientEventHandler(): gattClientEventHandler [esp_gatt_if: 4] ... Unknown
[D][BLEDevice.cpp:148] gattClientEventHandler(): gattClientEventHandler [esp_gatt_if: 4] ... Unknown
[D][BLEClient.cpp:177] gattClientEventHandler(): gattClientEventHandler [esp_gatt_if: 4] ... Unknown
[D][BLEDevice.cpp:148] gattClientEventHandler(): gattClientEventHandler [esp_gatt_if: 4] ... Unknown
[D][BLEClient.cpp:177] gattClientEventHandler(): gattClientEventHandler [esp_gatt_if: 4] ... Unknown
[D][BLEDevice.cpp:148] gattClientEventHandler(): gattClientEventHandler [esp_gatt_if: 4] ... Unknown
[D][BLEClient.cpp:177] gattClientEventHandler(): gattClientEventHandler [esp_gatt_if: 4] ... Unknown
[D][BLEDevice.cpp:148] gattClientEventHandler(): gattClientEventHandler [esp_gatt_if: 4] ... Unknown
[D][BLEClient.cpp:177] gattClientEventHandler(): gattClientEventHandler [esp_gatt_if: 4] ... Unknown
[D][BLEDevice.cpp:148] gattClientEventHandler(): gattClientEventHandler [esp_gatt_if: 4] ... Unknown
[D][BLEClient.cpp:177] gattClientEventHandler(): gattClientEventHandler [esp_gatt_if: 4] ... Unknown
[D][BLEDevice.cpp:148] gattClientEventHandler(): gattClientEventHandler [esp_gatt_if: 4] ... Unknown
[D][BLEClient.cpp:177] gattClientEventHandler(): gattClientEventHandler [esp_gatt_if: 4] ... Unknown
[D][BLEDevice.cpp:148] gattClientEventHandler(): gattClientEventHandler [esp_gatt_if: 4] ... Unknown
[D][BLEClient.cpp:177] gattClientEventHandler(): gattClientEventHandler [esp_gatt_if: 4] ... Unknown
[D][BLEDevice.cpp:148] gattClientEventHandler(): gattClientEventHandler [esp_gatt_if: 4] ... Unknown
[D][BLEClient.cpp:177] gattClientEventHandler(): gattClientEventHandler [esp_gatt_if: 4] ... Unknown
[D][BLEDevice.cpp:148] gattClientEventHandler(): gattClientEventHandler [esp_gatt_if: 4] ... Unknown
[D][BLEClient.cpp:177] gattClientEventHandler(): gattClientEventHandler [esp_gatt_if: 4] ... Unknown
[D][BLEDevice.cpp:148] gattClientEventHandler(): gattClientEventHandler [esp_gatt_if: 4] ... Unknown
[D][BLEClient.cpp:177] gattClientEventHandler(): gattClientEventHandler [esp_gatt_if: 4] ... Unknown
 - Found service ( fb005c80-02e7-f387-1cad-8acd2d8df0c8 )
[D][BLERemoteService.cpp:193] retrieveCharacteristics(): Found a characteristic: Handle: 63, UUID: fb005c81-02e7-f387-1cad-8acd2d8df0c8
[D][BLERemoteCharacteristic.cpp:293] retrieveDescriptors(): Found a descriptor: Handle: 64, UUID: 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[D][BLERemoteService.cpp:193] retrieveCharacteristics(): Found a characteristic: Handle: 66, UUID: fb005c82-02e7-f387-1cad-8acd2d8df0c8
[D][BLERemoteCharacteristic.cpp:293] retrieveDescriptors(): Found a descriptor: Handle: 67, UUID: 00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
characteristics
 - characteristic UUID : fb005c81-02e7-f387-1cad-8acd2d8df0c8 Broadcast:X Read:O WriteNoResponse:X Write:O Notify:X Indicate:O
 - characteristic UUID : fb005c82-02e7-f387-1cad-8acd2d8df0c8 Broadcast:X Read:X WriteNoResponse:X Write:X Notify:O Indicate:X
 - Add Notify ( fb005c82-02e7-f387-1cad-8acd2d8df0c8 )
[D][BLEDevice.cpp:148] gattClientEventHandler(): gattClientEventHandler [esp_gatt_if: 4] ... Unknown
[D][BLEClient.cpp:177] gattClientEventHandler(): gattClientEventHandler [esp_gatt_if: 4] ... Unknown
[D][BLEDevice.cpp:148] gattClientEventHandler(): gattClientEventHandler [esp_gatt_if: 4] ... Unknown
[D][BLEClient.cpp:177] gattClientEventHandler(): gattClientEventHandler [esp_gatt_if: 4] ... Unknown

 - Can Notify
[D][BLEDevice.cpp:148] gattClientEventHandler(): gattClientEventHandler [esp_gatt_if: 4] ... Unknown
[D][BLEClient.cpp:177] gattClientEventHandler(): gattClientEventHandler [esp_gatt_if: 4] ... Unknown
[D][BLEDevice.cpp:148] gattClientEventHandler(): gattClientEventHandler [esp_gatt_if: 4] ... Unknown
[D][BLEClient.cpp:177] gattClientEventHandler(): gattClientEventHandler [esp_gatt_if: 4] ... Unknown
now connected to BLE Server.
```

Comment: Please test your Polar OH1+ using the [nRF Connect app](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Software-and-tools/Development-Tools/nRF-Connect-for-mobile). If Reading, Writing and subscribing to notification works you know for sure that it's a problem with the esp32 code and not something else

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried to see if I could read, write, and notify using the nRF Connetct app. Also, by changing the source code, we were able to get similar results to the nRF Connect app. The changes are described in [Polar_Measurement_Data_Specification.pdf](https://github.com/polarofficial/polar-ble-sdk/blob/master/technical_documentation/Polar_Measurement_Data_Specification.pdf).The change was to set the MTU by referring to the "Prerequisite" written in "Polar_Measurement_Data_Specification.pdf".

Comment: However, in both cases, NOTIFY did not work and the PMD Control Point returned an error.
I wrote the bytes in the "start stream" section of the same PDF.
The error value is "5", and the PDF says that I am entering the wrong parameters.
Can you tell me what exactly is wrong?

Comment: Did you manage to enable notifications or did this fail as well?

Comment: In the case of Polar OH1+, the PMD Control Point returned "0xF0 0x02 0x02 0x05 0x00" and the notifications did not work.
However, when I tried with Polar H10, the notifications worked fine.
If you write the correct value to the PMD Control Point, the notifications will work.
The value returned from the PMD Control Point is "0x05", which means that the wrong parameter is being written.
I don't know what value I should write to the PMD Control Point.

Comment: Could you try sending just `0x01 0x02` to the control point? The document you provided uses this as an example in "Request Stream Settings". It seems like you have to ask for the settings first and use those to start the Stream

Comment: I sent `0x01 0x02` and it returned the correct settings. After setting the bytes to write based on that setting, the stream started and I was able to receive the acceleration.
Thank you very much.

Comment: But I am sorry, I would like to read ppi (pulse-pulse interval).
When I send `0x01 0x03`, it returns `0xf0 0x01 0x03 0x00 0x00` and very little data to set.
So I sent only `0x02 0x03`, the byte to be written to start the stream, and the stream started successfully.
But I don't know how much of the returned data is which data. Can you tell me?
[Send a piece of data.](https://nitkisarazu-my.sharepoint.com/:t:/g/personal/d17303_inc_kisarazu_ac_jp/ESuBAKUB28tBjDlFqTNcWqMBwe_TBYof6nEDs8g2c94Zyg?e=eJAy4d)

Comment: My guess is that the Bytes sequence is `measurement type (1byte),time stamp?(8byte),frame type(1byte),data(6byte) ... (6 bytes repeated)`.
The "Frame types PPI" in the document says that the first byte of the data is Heart rate in bpm, but I think this is an unstable and high value for that. What should I think about this?
I guessed from the Bytes sequence of ACC written in "Start Stream".

Comment: Quite difficult to say really, the documentation is not very clear... What was the heart rate during the measurement approximately? Maybe we can figure something out that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [specification](https://github.com/polarofficial/polar-ble-sdk/blob/master/technical_documentation/Polar_Measurement_Data_Specification.pdf) you provided shows the correct flow of messages needed to start streaming. You have to start by requesting the streaming settings first.

For requesting the ppi settings just send `0x01 0x03` to the P=MD control point.

While looking at the source code of the polar-ble-sdk I found this in [BlePMDClient.java](https://github.com/polarofficial/polar-ble-sdk/blob/d7c476f03f009cc0649901f7b404243440b86369/sources/Android/android-communications/src/main/java/com/androidcommunications/polar/api/ble/model/gatt/client/BlePMDClient.java#L697) (I added comments to the relevant parts):

```java
public static class PpiData {
    public static class PPSample {
        public final int hr;
        public final int ppInMs;
        public final int ppErrorEstimate;
        public final int blockerBit;
        public final int skinContactStatus;
        public final int skinContactSupported;

        public PPSample(@NonNull byte[] data) {
            // Convert data[0] to heart rate using a bitwise AND operation
            // with 0xFF as long
            hr = (int) ((long) data[0] & 0xFFL);
            // Convert data[0] and data[1] to time between peaks in ms using
            // BleUtils.convertArrayToUnsignedLong
            ppInMs = (int) BleUtils.convertArrayToUnsignedLong(data, 1, 2);
            // Same for the error estimate
            ppErrorEstimate = (int) BleUtils.convertArrayToUnsignedLong(data, 3, 2);
            // The last byte contains multiple flags that get read by
            // bitshifting. First bit is the blockerBit, second the
            // skinContactStatus, third skinContactSupported
            blockerBit = data[5] & 0x01;
            skinContactStatus = (data[5] & 0x02) >> 1;
            skinContactSupported = (data[5] & 0x04) >> 2;
        }
    }

    public final List<PPSample> ppSamples = new ArrayList<>();
    public final long timeStamp;

    public PpiData(@NonNull byte[] data, long timeStamp) {
        int offset = 0;
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
        while (offset < data.length) {
            final int finalOffset = offset;
            ppSamples.add(new PPSample(Arrays.copyOfRange(data, finalOffset, finalOffset + 6)));
            offset += 6;
        }
    }
}
```

Now we know how to convert the 6 bytes of the data frame, but the data you receive has mostly 40 bytes and looks like this:

`03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 34 02 1e 00 07 00 f2 01 1e 00 07 00 05 03 1e 00 07 00 63 03 1e 00 06 00 8e 03 1e 00 06`

The conversion from the raw data to the different data frames happens in [Line 888](https://github.com/polarofficial/polar-ble-sdk/blob/d7c476f03f009cc0649901f7b404243440b86369/sources/Android/android-communications/src/main/java/com/androidcommunications/polar/api/ble/model/gatt/client/BlePMDClient.java#L888) of the same file.

The first 10 bytes of the received data is extracted here:

```java
PmdMeasurementType type = PmdMeasurementType.fromId(data[0]);
final long timeStamp = BleUtils.convertArrayToUnsignedLong(data, 1, 8);
final long frameType = BleUtils.convertArrayToUnsignedLong(data, 9, 1);
final byte[] content = new byte[data.length - 10];
System.arraycopy(data, 10, content, 0, content.length);
```

Looking at the data you received we now know the following:

| Type | Data | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PmdMeasurementType | `03` | The type of data, here it is the same as the requested. 3 = PPI |
| Timestamp | `00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00` | The timestamp, somehow 0 here |
| Frametype | `00` | Type of data that follows |
| content | `00 34 02 1e 00 07 00 f2 01 1e 00 07 00 05 03 1e 00 07 00 63 03 1e 00 06 00 8e 03 1e 00 06` | The rest of the raw data is called content and gets used further |

Since we are looking at PPI data the following case of the switch-case applies:

```java
case PPI:
    if (frameType == 0) {
        RxUtils.emitNext(ppiObservers, object -> object.onNext(new PpiData(content, timeStamp)));
    } else {
        BleLogger.w(TAG, "Unknown PPI frame type received");
    }
    break;
```

Only a frametype of zero is allowed here and this is exactly what you received. You sometimes received 40 bytes and other times only 16. Since the first 10 are not part of the actual data we can now assume that the 40 bytes contain 5 PPI measurements (5 * 6 bytes = 30 bytes) and the 16 bytes contain only one measurement.

If we take a look at the first PPI measurement in the dataset you received we can now read the following:

| Raw data | Type | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `00` | Heart rate | 0 |
| `34 02` | Peak to peak in ms | 564 ms |
| `1e 00` | Peak to peak error estimate | 30 |
| `07` -> `00000111` | Error bit, skin contact status bit, skin contact status supported bit | Error: true, skin contact: true, skin contact supported: true |

Since you do not have a heart rate reading and the error bit is set I would assume something went wrong, maybe you did not wear the device while testing.

Comment: Thank you!
Thanks to you, I could get ppi!